# Is Port 13330 a standard-port?

Tags: tcp

I saw some programs using the port 13330. What is the meaning of this port? Is this port used by a special program?

Answer (score 8):

This is most definitely not a standard port. I typically use these 3 sites for determining what a TCP port's been designated for:

- [Service Name and Transport Protocol Port Number Registry](http://www.iana.org/assignments/service-names-port-numbers/service-names-port-numbers.txt)
- [Port Numbers - Internet Assigned Numbers Authority](http://www.iana.org/assignments/service-names-port-numbers/service-names-port-numbers.xml)
- [Assignments/port-numbers - IETF](http://www.ietf.org/assignments/port-numbers)

The first 2 are from IANA - Internet Assigned Numbers Authority. This is *THE* authority when it comes to designating the usage of numbers on the Internet.

The 3rd link is here for historical purposes. It's related to the IETF - Internet Engineering Task Force. The purpose of the document was to outline how the port numbers would be managed.

**NOTE:** Linux distributions (and probably others unixoid systems) also have a file called `/etc/services` which contains the port numbers assignment.

Comment: I'm not sure how far back history of /etc/services goes, but it's definitely not a Linux invention.

Comment: @lgeorget added that to my answer which I was OK with but didn't include in the original answer. I  think it's important information so that passer-bys know that the file `/etc/services` is what drives the names that get displayed for the different ports. But @sendmoreinfo is 100% correct, that files has been around since I started out with Solaris, probably even older than that.

Comment: @slm Yes, that's what I added "and probably others unixoid systems" :-). I'm only aware that this file exists on all the Linux distributions I've tried so far so I guess it's an old UNIX legacy but I don't know its whole history.

Answer (score -1):

According to [this website](http://www.planetlinks.com/tec236/notes-terms/4-10-06/default-tcp-ports-list.html), 13330 is *not* a standard port for TCP (question is tagged as TCP,) so it has no special usage. However, there is no *official* standard port list, so there is no way to know what ports are official and what ports are not.

Comment: Err... yes, such a list does exist. Ok, there is nothing wrong with running other service than a web server on port 80, and it's perfectly ok to use another port than 80 to run the web server but, nevertheless, the IANA _defines_ port 80 as the web port.

Comment: If you can find me said list, I stand corrected :)

Comment: @rtainc The IANA documents linked from the other answer are as official as it gets. Nothing prevents a random admin from running what he likes on that port, of course, but that's outside the scope of this question.